# Generating oauth token on sandbox throws ServerError

Tags: ordercloud

When generating oauth token from ordercloud sandbox environment, ordercloud returns ServerError as the error. Double checked the client_id, username, password and grant_type and it is correct. I am able to generate token using client_credentials grant_type. Is there a different way to generate token using password grant_type?

```
"client_id": "827D3F9E-F0AE-4C12-AF55-24D1D526303F",
"grant_type": "password",
"username": "admin02",
"password": "Test1234567#",
"scope": "CatalogAdmin BuyerReader MeAdmin InventoryAdmin PasswordReset OrderAdmin PriceScheduleAdmin ProductAdmin ProductAssignmentAdmin ShipmentAdmin"

"ErrorCode": "ServerError",
"Message": "An unknown error has occurred on the server.",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your API Client has a ClientSecret set and you are not passing the ClientSecret in the request body. If you remove the ClientSecret, or pass it in the request body, your call should succeed.

It should be returning a 400 though rather than 500, so I will log that as a bug on our end.

Comment: Why should we pass client_secret for password grant_type? If the grant_type is client_credentials, then it makes sense to pass the client_secret without username and password. Anyway I tried to pass the client secret as well, I am getting 500 response.

Comment: If you have a ClientSecret defined it must always be passed, no exceptions. We don't generally recommend using a ClientSecret on an API client that will be used for password grant types, but there is nothing stopping you from configuring it that way.

I can see you made a request and included a ClientSecret - but it does not match the ClientSecret for your API Client which is why it is still failing.